# UIButton Hidden property strange behaviour - iOS

Tags: ios, uibutton

I want to hide an button if my array is not nil using the following code however, for some reason it is not working. I cannot see any mistakes in my code.. Please help me.. Thanks..

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *title = nil;

     HowtoUseButton = [[[CustomButton alloc] init] autorelease];

    [HowtoUseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(openLink) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    HowtoUseButton.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 140.0, 160.0, 70.0);


    [self.view addSubview:HowtoUseButton];


    if (document.count > 0){

        HowtoUseButton.hidden = YES;  // not working
        title = Title_Doc;

    }
    else if (self.documentURLs.count == 0){

        title = Title_No_Doc;
        HowtoUseButton.hidden = NO;

    }

    return title;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using this in `titleForHeaderInSection`, it is probably being called more than once.  And if that is the case, perhaps only some of the buttons are hidden.

Try changing:

```
HowtoUseButton = [[[CustomButton alloc] init] autorelease];
[HowtoUseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(openLink) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
HowtoUseButton.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 140.0, 160.0, 70.0);
[self.view addSubview:HowtoUseButton];
```

to:

```
if (!HowtoUseButton) {
    HowtoUseButton = [[[CustomButton alloc] init] autorelease];
    [HowtoUseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(openLink) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    HowtoUseButton.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 140.0, 160.0, 70.0);
    [self.view addSubview:HowtoUseButton];
}
```

Also, as the other people who have already answered have said, this really shouldn't here in the first place.  Create the button in interface builder, or in `viewDidLoad` once, and simply set the hidden property where you need to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `hidden` property, why not just remove it from the view?

```
[HowtoUseButton removeFromSuperview];
```

As an aside, I will note that what you are doing here is somewhat strange. If you want a button in the table view section header, the best way to go about this is probably to implement:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

...in your table view delegate. That way, you can completely customize the table header view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove button creation part from `titleForHeader` method keep this code in `viewDidLoad` method of your class,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   HowtoUseButton = [[[CustomButton alloc] init] autorelease];
   [HowtoUseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(openLink) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
   HowtoUseButton.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 140.0, 160.0, 70.0);
   [self.view addSubview:HowtoUseButton];
```

Since you are creating this in `titleForHeader` method, it is getting created multiple times and you will lose the reference to the old one, once the new one is created. `titleForHeader` method will be called whenever you scroll the tableview. Instead you can just create it once in your `viewDidLoad` method and use it.

And if you are trying to add this button to table view header, please use `viewForHeaderInSection` as mentioned in the other answer.